# How do I target and add a class to the textarea in contact7 form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contact-form-7

I am currently working on styling a contact7 form and have run into a slight issue because the jquery snippet I am using(I am a javascript/jquery newbie)  only affects inputs and not text areas. For some reason contact7's text section calls an input yet the textarea doesn't, it only uses textarea. Both input and textarea are automatically generated by cf7.

Right now my text and email fields are working as expected and am trying to figure out how to add and remove classes to the textarea. As mentioned I am a newbie so any guidance would be appreciated.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('input').focus(function(){
            $(this).parents('.form-label-outer').addClass('focused');
        });

        $('input').blur(function(){
            var inputValue = $(this).val();
            if ( inputValue == "" ) {
                $(this).removeClass('filled');
                $(this).parents('.form-label-outer').removeClass('focused');  
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('filled');
            }
        })
    });
</script>

<form action="/contact/?preview_id=8&amp;preview_nonce=1ac0cc6b7e&amp;_thumbnail_id=-1&amp;preview=true#wpcf7-f28580-p8-o4" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="28580">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.1.1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f28580-p8-o4">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="8">
<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label-outer"><span class="form-label">What is your name?</span> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </label> /* Event triggered on input (input automatically generated by cf7) */
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label-outer"><span class="form-label">What is your email?</span><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></label> /* Event triggered on input (input automatically generated by cf7) */
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
      <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> /* Need to trigger event on textarea (textarea automatically generated by cf7) */
    </div>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"><span class="ajax-loader"></span></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>
```

What I would like to achive is to add and subtract the above mentioned classes to the textarea also.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you're looking for is `$('input, textarea')`.

Comment: If I add the selectors together as suggested or seperately, I am unable to type in the input areas. The jquery is also nit triggered. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to apply the same thing to the text area as well ie on focus you need to remove **form-label-outer** class and add **focused** class similarly you need to do some action on blur as well. I would suggest you keep a common class for both **input and text area** and pass that class in the above function.

or

You can create an id for the text area alone and you can pass that id to the function.

Make sure you have **form-label-outer** class to the parent of the input or text area otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Thank you for the input, unfrotunately the textarea and input is automatically generated by cf7 so I cannot change the id's. I have added the contact form's source code if that helps.